# MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name

Tags: java

I know that there are a lot of questions and answers exactly about this error on stackoverflow and other forums. But I still can not find the solution...

***My code:***

```
package com.sodifrance.apex.presentation.generic.utils;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class EnumTranslator {

    private static EnumTranslator instance = null;

    private EnumTranslator() {
    }

    public static EnumTranslator getDefaut() {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new EnumTranslator();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public String translate(Enum<?> enumerationValue) {
        String localizedMessage = "";

        if (enumerationValue != null)
        {
            ResourceBundle b = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.enumerations");

            localizedMessage = enumerationValue.name();

            if (b != null)
            {
                localizedMessage = b.getString(enumerationValue.getDeclaringClass().getName() + "." + enumerationValue.name());
            }
        }

        return localizedMessage;
    }
}
```

***Tomcat Console:***

> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name
>   resources.enumerations, locale fr_FR  at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)  at
>   com.presentation.generic.utils.EnumTranslator.translate(EnumTranslator.java:25)
>     at
>   com.presentation.entry.societe.EntryChoixTypeSocieteAction.execute(EntryChoixTypeSocieteAction.java:53)
>     at
>   com.presentation.generic.back.BackRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(BackRequestProcessor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
>     at
>   com.presentation.generic.back.BackRequestProcessor.process(BackRequestProcessor.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   com.presentation.generic.security.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   com.presentation.generic.security.ApplicationFilter.doFilter(ApplicationFilter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

when i inspect this line in debbug mode:

```
ResourceBundle b = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.enumerations");
```

I have this message:

> The method getBundle(String) is undefined for the type Enum Translator

***My file config:***
[image]

Comment: where do you put your property file ?

Comment: @JérémieB i have update my post with property file

Comment: try getBundle("com.sod.ap.properties.enumerations")

Comment: @JérémieB it's good for me, post your answer. Merci l'ami ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource.getBundle take a FQCN as a parameters. In the statement `ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.enumerations")`, the JRE are looking for the files resources/enumerations<_local>.properties

In your example, you should use `getBundle("com.sod.ap.properties.enumerations")`